# Pypyodbc: Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found") error when trying to connect to SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, freetds, pypyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server using Pypyodbc on Mac and I'm getting the following error:

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'FreeTDS' : file not found")
```

I have installed freeTDS and unixodbc

```
brew install unixodbc
brew install freetds
```

and here is my connection String with dummy data:

```
connection_String = "Driver=FreeTDS;Server=123.12.12.12;tds_version=7.2;Database=db_db;Uid=username:pwd=password:port=1433"
```

Comment: [Does this SO post answer you question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678696/sql-server-python-and-os-x)

Comment: Not a Mac guy, but in other *nix systems, I'd check that the FreeTDS so files are in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: The answer that I posted [on a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46793344/648162) may help if you have this issue.

Answer (score 16):

Check your /etc/odbcinst.ini or it could be under /etc/unixODBC/odbcinst.ini

In your connection string you have something like this "DRIVER=FreeTDS" there needs to be an entry in that file like the following.  You may need to change your driver location.

```
[FreeTDS]
Description             = FreeTDS unixODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Setup           = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
UsageCount              = 1
```

Comment: libtdsodbc.so.0 doesn't exist on OSX

Comment: It's called libtdsodbc.0.so for some reason, mine (installed by brew) is in `/etc/local/lib/libtdsodbc.0.so`.

Comment: Can anyone tell me where odbcinst.ini lives on M1 macs in Monterey? nothing in etc seems to be working...

Answer (score 11):

First, you can use [pymssql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/) which doesn't require configuring unixODBC, which is the problem here.

To configure unixODBC with FreeTDS, do the following: http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html

There's a tool that comes with FreeTDS, tsql. Use it to test your connection string. It's a very bare bones tool and something of a pain. :-/

Finally, there's a similar question with other problems in StackOverflow: [How do I configure pyodbc to correctly accept strings from SQL Server using freeTDS and unixODBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828688/how-do-i-configure-pyodbc-to-correctly-accept-strings-from-sql-server-using-free)

Comment: the link to configure unixODBC with FreeTDS is great, except there's no "libtdsodbc.so" anywhere on OS X

Comment: In Archlinux, it's part of a package called "freetds". Maybe you can install that library.

Comment: @andrei if you already have Freetds installed, brew uninstall it first, then brew install freetds --with-unixodbc fixed my problem. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074751/freetds-missing-libtdsodbc-so-file-on-osx

Comment: first, I got pyodbc working, then i decided to upgrade python to python3 (or rather install another version along side python2) and now i can't get it to work again.

Comment: On MacOS Monterey, brew install freetds --with-unixodbc throws the error: invalid option: --with-unixodbc . Option is no longer required, see https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/257