# Pyodbc Azure sql database

Tags: azure-sql-database, pyodbc

I am using a macOs BigSur, and I would like to use python to connect to azure sql database.

I followed Microsoft documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/sql?view=azure-python

to set all the configuration and installed all the requirement for the Mac OS following this documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15

but when I run my python script I get this error:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I install mssql-tools and unixodbc

and if I run the command `odbcinst -j`

I get back this output:

```
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/<my-user>/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Anyone has a clue about this error? and please if you need more infos just ask me. Thank you so much

EDIT:
Following the documentation, Microsoft suggests to make a sim link out of the odic.ini and odbcinst.ini.
I run the code to create those symlinks but I realised that if I try to open those files, they are empty, and if I try to go to the folder and open them manually rather than with terminal, I get the error that it can't be done because the source doesn't exist.
Did anyone ever occurred in this error?

LATEST UPDATE:
I installed FreeTDS and updated my .odbc.ini with the following configuration:

```
[my_server]
Description = my_server
TDS_Version = 7.4
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Server = YOUR.SERVERNAME.HERE.com
Port = 1433
```

When I run my python script to connect to the database, I get the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 11, in <module>
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('dsn=my_server;'
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

And in fact there is no `libtdsodbc.so` in that location.
In another topic they suggest to install freeTDS with the flag `--with-unixodbc` but when I try to do so, I get the error that the command doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATE

If your macos is on the x64 architecture, you can use below method to solve issues.

If you use M1, it's not support now.

[image]

---

**Solution for `x64 architecture`.**

Run below code, it should useful to you.

```
brew update
brew install unixodbc
brew install FreeTDS
```

Then update the `.odbc.ini` file.

**For more details, please refer below blogs.**

[How to set up ODBC in Mac OS to connect to MS SQL Server for use with Python and R](https://www.nelsontang.com/odbc-in-OSX/)

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your help. But unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem. I installed freetds but I get the error that `libtdsodbc.so` doesn't exist, and in fact it doesn't. and if I try to install freetds using `--with-uniodbc` I get the error that the command doesn't exist

Comment: @NaydenVan Can you update your post with error pic what you meet ?

Comment: @NaydenVan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180843/python-cant-open-lib-libtdsodbc-so-file-not-found

Comment: @NaydenVan Try to use other version for macos.

Comment: Having the same issue. :(

Comment: I missed an important bit. On the Microsoft documentation, they state that the macOS M1 are not supported. I need to find another solution

Comment: @NaydenVan Can I update my answer with M1 are not supported ? I think it will help more forum users.

Comment: [M1 is now supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16) (from v17.8 onwards).

Answer (score 0):

Starting ODBC version 17.8, Apple M1 is [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16).

You can install ODBC 18 on macOS with the following commands:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update

HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```